# Trouble using operator while generating two character domain names a-z 0-9

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am wanting to get advice on what I am missing over an answer to this if possible.

Expected output is aa, ab, ac,... a8, a9, all the way through zz, z1,..., z8, z9
It makes it to a8, a9 and then pulls the error for the first Inner loop

This is for my Computer Science class. I was given a code that generates aa, ab, ac, ... zy, zz. I need to add 0-9 after 'z' on the second character and am running into trouble with str and int with operators:

```
print('Two-letter domain names:')

letter1 = 'a'
letter2 = '?'
while letter1 <= 'z':  # Outer loop
    letter2 = 'a'
    while letter2 <= 'z':  # Inner loop | TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
        print('{}{}.com'.format(letter1, letter2))
        letter2 = chr(ord(letter2) + 1)
        while letter2 == '{':     # My bit
            letter2 = 0
            for letter2 in range(10):
                print('{}{}.com'.format(letter1, letter2))
                letter2 = letter2 + 1
    letter1 = chr(ord(letter1) + 1)
```

```
letter2 = chr(ord(letter2) + 1)# TypeError: ord() expected string of length 1, but int found
letter2 = chr((letter2) + 1)# Infinite loop
letter2 = chr(letter2) + 1# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str | makes it to a0
```

```
                if letter2 == '9':
                    letter2 = chr(letter2)# Does nothing
```

I have spent a couple hours on this and after searching and only finding answers to similar TypeError saying to add 'int()' to the input, but have had no luck trying myself.

Comment: It might be a good idea to add the expected output of your program or at least explain the purpose of it in your own words.

Comment: So I believe Python3 does the `ord()` conversion for you, it's part of the update. Also, the Python byte array and bytes objects yield integers when iterating, not characters so removing the `ord()` call should do the trick...so indexing into a bytes object gives you the value of that byte as an integer. That's why that error is showing up.

Comment: @FishingCode After trying this, I got an infinite loop :/

Answer (score 1):

You would build off of the previous stage. The loop for letter2 is already there for the letters. Just change the letters to numbers. letter2 = 'a' becomes letter2 = '0' and letter2 <='z' becomes letter2 <=9. everything else stays the same. The indentations need to be the same as the previous letter2 steps as well as it is essentially the same step.

See below

```
print('Two-letter domain names:')

letter1 = 'a'
letter2 = '?'
while letter1 <= 'z':  # Outer loop
    letter2 = 'a'
    while letter2 <= 'z':  # Inner loop
        print('{}{}.com'.format(letter1, letter2))
        letter2 = chr(ord(letter2) + 1)
    letter2 = '0'
    while letter2 <= '9':
        print('{}{}.com'.format(letter1, letter2))
        letter2 = chr(ord(letter2) + 1)
    letter1 = chr(ord(letter1) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, add an extra pair of paratheses. Like so:

```
letter2 = chr(**(**ord(letter2)**)** + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution was there all along. Just missing the indentation.

```
while letter2 == '{':     # My bit
            letter2 = 0
            for letter2 in range(10):
                print('{}{}.com'.format(letter1, letter2))
                letter2 = letter2 + 1
```

This needed to run along side the inner loop and not inside the inner loop

```
print('Two-letter domain names:')

letter1 = 'a'
letter2 = '?'
while letter1 <= 'z':  # Outer loop
    letter2 = 'a'
    while letter2 <= 'z':  # Inner loop | TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'
        print('{}{}.com'.format(letter1, letter2))
        letter2 = chr(ord(letter2) + 1)
    while letter2 == '{':     # My bit
        letter2 = 0
        for letter2 in range(10):
            print('{}{}.com'.format(letter1, letter2))
            letter2 = letter2 + 1
    letter1 = chr(ord(letter1) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

To generate 'aa', 'ab', 'ac'...'a1', 'a2', 'a3'...'zz', 'z1', 'z2'...

It is very simple, we can use a two level nested for loop, get the index and element by using `enumerate`, and loop through all elements starting at the current index and join them.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters, digits

result = []
alphabet = letters + digits
for i, letter in enumerate(letters):
    for letter2 in alphabet[i:]:
        result.append(f'{letter}{letter2}.com')
```

We can use a list comprehension to make code more concise:

```
result = [f'{a}{b}.com' for i, a in enumerate(letters) for b in alphabet[i:]]
```

---

Note I don't know what the original poster wants, since the code is not working.

But if the task is to generate all pairings of a-z and a-z+0+9, just use `itertools.product`:

```
from itertools import product
from string import ascii_lowercase as letters, digits

result = [f'{a}{b}.com' for a, b in product(letters, letters + digits)]
```

Or alternatively use `map`:

```
result = list(map('{}{}.com'.format, *zip(*product(letters, letters + digits))))
```

On more reading I have just found out that the task was to generate all pairings between a-z and a-z+1-9, so it is the second scenario and all answers posted before are wrong. It is trivial to remove the pairings that contain a zero, but I don't see any reason to exclude it.